# Creating an Events Feed with Sub Pages/Posts for Each Event

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical, events

I am currently working on creating an events section for a website. My original plan was to create a custom post type for Events and create a new post for each event. Then I would query the top five events on the home page. My problem is that I need to have sub pages/posts for each event.  These pages/posts will need to show up in a sidebar when the single event post is viewed. Is that possible?

Can I create a parent/child relationship with each event post and its sub posts or would it be better to use custom taxonomies to organize this information? The site will be client updated, so I need to create a system that is straightforward and sustainable with a logical permalink structure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a custom post type, and make it hierarchical, it will behave like pages. so you can have sub events the same way you have sub pages.

look at `register_post_type` function arguments here :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

then use `wp_list_pages` function to list subpages. see :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type

something like this (not tested) :

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'title_li'  => '',
  'child_of'  => $post->ID,
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'title_li'  => __('Sub events'),
  'echo'      => 0,
)
$children = wp_list_pages( $args );
if ( $children ) {
?>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $children ?>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

please, see [this topic on the WordPress forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_list_pages-and-hierarchical-custom-post-type) also.

all you need seems to be in the codex. do not hesitate to follow its rules. here you will find nearly all the tools you wish :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

seb.

Comment: I have created a hierarchical custom post type called Events and it is working great. I am now able to list sub-posts for each event in a sidebar using wp_list_pages as you suggested. My only problem is that I cannot figure out how to highlight the current post in the menu. I am used to using .current_page_item, but this does not seem to apply to custom posts. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: sorry, i recieved no warning for your next question...

it seems that you are right. the current_page_item is not displayed :(

i've modified the code a bit so you may try this instead :

`<?php
$args = array(
  'child_of'  => array_pop( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) ),
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'title_li'  => __('Sub events'),
  'echo'      => 0,
);

$children = preg_replace( '/page-item-' . $post->ID . '/', 'current_page_item page-item-' . $post->ID, wp_list_pages( $args ) );
if ( $children ) {
?>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $children ?>
  </ul>
<?php
}
?>`

Comment: arg ! this is ugly ! i've made 2 changes : replace `$children = wp_list_pages( $args );` with `$children = preg_replace( '/page-item-' . $post->ID . '/', 'current_page_item page-item-' . $post->ID, wp_list_pages( $args ) );`

Comment: and `'child_of' => $post->ID,` with `'child_of' => array_pop( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) ),` so the menu will work in your sub events showing the top level ancestors with all childs.

Comment: Or even, remove the `chil_of` parameter so you will have the complete tree :) Well it depends on what you want to display....